# Can I nUse not equal for for loop

Tags: java

Sorry to ask a newbie question.

Let say I am to use for loop for a method and I need to break out when the condition is met.

So can I use not equal in the for loop like

Code

```
String p;

If(p = snake){
Break;}
Else
{
For(I=0; I != break; I++){
System.out.println(“Please enter your favourite pet: ”);
P = ent.nextString();
}
}
```

code

Comment: You can put there whatever condition you want. In this case `do while` loop might be more suited tho.

Comment: Additionally to what was already said here, `if (p = snake)` does not check for equality. `p = snake` would assign the value of `snake` to `p`. If you want to compare equality for objects you use `==`. But in the case of comparing a String value, you wouldn't want to compare the objects, but the values. This is done via `if (p.equals("snake"))`.

Comment: the code you posted is not valid Java (case sensitive). '=' is an assignment operator, not a comparison.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to express by `I != break`? `I` is a number, `break` is a control flow keyword.

Comment: I think you may have to read a few tutorials. I'd recommend Oracle's [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). There are a lot of things going on in this code that tells me you may be misunderstanding how it works. Like, you can't put a break outside the loop and your "keywords", like `if`, `else` and `break` start with uppercase, making them not actually keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can but for such situation there is a `while` loop

```
while(!conditionToBreak) {
    // do something

    if(shouldBreak()) {
        conditionToBreak = true;
    }
}
```

About this loop (and similar `do-while`) you can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

---

Also - review your code because in current state it will not work - e.g. `I != break` is wrong because `break` is a keyword